# Abrir fragment desde activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Como puedo abrir el fragment ItvList desde la Snackbar del activity AddItv?

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.CalendarContract
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import com.ramon.tonig.Global.AppDb
import com.ramon.ttguti.R

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_create_fechas.*
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*



class AddItv : AppCompatActivity() {

    internal var rbSelected: String = ""

    private var button_date: Button? = null
    private var btSalvar: Button? = null

    var fechaItv = Calendar.getInstance()
    var fecha6 = Calendar.getInstance()
    var fecha12 = Calendar.getInstance()

    private var itv: Itv? = null
    private var listItv: List<Itv>? = null
    private var escribirBaseDatosTask: EscribirBaseDatosTask? = null
    private var leerBaseDatosTask: LeerBaseDatosTask? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_fechas)

        configView()
    }

    private fun configView() {
        itv = Itv()
        listItv = ArrayList()

        listItv = AppDb.getAppDb(applicationContext).itvDAO().findAllItv()

        leerBaseDatosTask = LeerBaseDatosTask()
        leerBaseDatosTask!!.execute()

        button_date = findViewById(R.id.btDate)
        btSalvar = findViewById(R.id.btGuardar)

        button_date!!.setOnClickListener {

                DatePickerDialog(this@AddItv,
                        dateSetListener,
                        // set DatePickerDialog to point to today's date when it loads up
                        fechaItv.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        fechaItv.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        fechaItv.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                        .show()
        }

        btSalvar!!.setOnClickListener {


            //Toast.makeText(applicationContext, rbSelected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() // print the value of selected super star

            Snackbar.make(it, "\n" + "Tus datos se han guardado corectamente", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Ok", View.OnClickListener {
                        fragmentTransaction(ItvList())
                        finish()
                    }).show()

            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd 'de 'MMMM 'del ' yyyy")


            itv!!.fe_itv_ultima = sdf.format(fechaItv.getTime())

            itv!!.notas = et_Notas.text.toString()

            escribirBaseDatosTask = EscribirBaseDatosTask()
            escribirBaseDatosTask!!.execute(itv)
        }
    }

    private fun fragmentTransaction(fragment: Fragment) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit()
    }

    val dateSetListener = object : DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker, year: Int, monthOfYear: Int,
                               dayOfMonth: Int) {
            fechaItv.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            fechaItv.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
            fechaItv.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)

            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd 'de 'MMMM yyyy")

            tvFechaUltima!!.text = sdf.format(fechaItv.getTime())
            fecha6.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear+6)
            fecha12.set(Calendar.YEAR, year+1)

            updateDateInView()
        }
    }

    private fun updateDateInView() {
        //val myFormat = "EE dd 'de 'MMMM yyyy" // mention the format you need
        //val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US)
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd 'de 'MMMM yyyy")
        //tvFecha!!.text = sdf.format(fechaItv.getTime())

        if (rb_uno!!.isChecked() && tvFechaUltima.text != null) {
            //rbSelected = rb_uno!!.text.toString()
            tvFechaProxima!!.text = sdf.format(fecha6.getTime())

            itv!!.fe_itv_proxima = sdf.format(fecha6.getTime())

            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT)
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event")
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Pasar ITV")
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Debes pasar la I.T.V. de tu coche")
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, fecha6.getTimeInMillis())
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, fecha6.getTimeInMillis())
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true)
            startActivity(intent)

        } else if (rb_dos!!.isChecked()) {
            //rbSelected = rb_dos!!.getText().toString()
            tvFechaProxima!!.text = sdf.format(fecha12.getTime())

            itv!!.fe_itv_proxima = sdf.format(fecha12.getTime())

            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT)
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event")
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Pasar ITV")
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Debes pasar la I.T.V. de tu coche")
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, fecha12.getTimeInMillis())
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, fecha12.getTimeInMillis())
            intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_ALL_DAY, true)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }

    private inner class EscribirBaseDatosTask : AsyncTask<Itv, Void, Void>() {

        override fun doInBackground(vararg itvs: Itv): Void? {
            AppDb.getAppDb(applicationContext).itvDAO().insertItv(itvs[0])
            return null
        }
    }

    private inner class LeerBaseDatosTask : AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Itv>>() {

        override fun doInBackground(vararg voids: Void): List<Itv>? {
            listItv = AppDb.getAppDb(applicationContext).itvDAO().findAllItv()
            return listItv
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(itvs: List<Itv>) {
            showItv(itvs)
        }
    }

    private fun showItv(itvs: List<Itv>) {
        for (itv in itvs) {
            Log.d("TAG", "ID: " + itv.id + " Nombre: " + itv.fe_itv_proxima + " Email: " + itv.seguro + "\n")
        }
    }


}
```

el ItvList Fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ramon.tonig.MiCocheBD.AddMiCocheAc">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/create_sqlite"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:typeface="sans"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="5dp">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="REVISION I.T.V"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Selecciona la duracion de la I.T.V"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

                <RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rb_uno"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:text="6 Meses"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rb_dos"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:checked="false"
                        android:text="12 Meses"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </RadioGroup>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:text="@string/fecha"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFechaUltima"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:text="Fecha Ultima"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btDate" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFechaProxima"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:text="Fecha Proxima"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFechaUltima" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_Notas"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:hint="Notas"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFechaProxima" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btGuardar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:text="@string/btn_gravar"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_Notas" />



            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout
```

Tranquila por la toolbarqu estw controlqada

Comment: Pon algo más de código. Por ejemplo, de la clase AddItv, al menos los imports y la declaración de clase. Y también la función ItvList()

Comment: Post editado con el codigo completo

Comment: ¿Y la función ItvList?

Comment: Pues no la conozco, soy un poco nuevo.

Comment: ¿No la tienes en el código? ¿Tampoco sabes si se genera automáticamente? ¿Te da algún error cuando compilas o ejecutas?

Comment: añadido el codigo del fragment

Comment: Si AddItv es una actividad que soporta fragmentos, creo que lo único que sobra es el finish() después de cambiar de fragmento ya que cerraría la actividad completa. Tampoco nos has indicado qué error te da o qué problema tienes exactamente

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82961/discussion-between-rafel-c-f-and-javi-molla).

Comment: @RafelC.F agrega el layout : activity_create_fechas.xml y te ayudo

Comment: @Jorgesys,ahi lo tienes, se que sabes y gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que varios usuarios te preguntaron por el método `ItvList()` ya que este se supone obtendría un fragment y al parecer es así ya que el error muestra otro problema en realidad:

> FragmentManager: No view found for id 0x7f090048
>   (com.ramon.ttguti:id/container) for fragment ItvList{3aa2269 #0
>   id=0x7f090048}

el problema es que no encuentra el contenedor donde realizar la transacción de tu `Fragment`,

```
private fun fragmentTransaction(fragment: Fragment) {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .commit()
}
```

para esto debes agregar un `FrameLayout` con id `container` en tu archivo `activity_create_fechas.xml` :

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Aquí se agregan Fragments" />
```

---

Es importante revises un poco sobre los `Fragments`, aquí un excelente tutorial:

[**Utilizar Fragmentos en una aplicación Android**](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/09/android-aplicaciones-fragmento/)

Answer (score -1):

podrias realizarlo de la siguiente manera.

```
        Snackbar.make(it, "\n" + "Tus datos se han guardado corectamente", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Ok", View.OnClickListener {
                    startActivity(new Intent(AddItv.this,ItvList.class))
                }).show()
```

Comment: ItvList  es un Fragment no Activity.